# Get Oracle PL/SQl variable property by name (reflection in PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, reflection, plsql, audit

I need to do some auditing on updating a row.

So I have a function that receives a parameter of type some_table%ROWTYPE, containing the new values to be saved for that row.

I also need to save some info in a history table regarding what column values where changed. I was thinking of getting the column names for some_table from all_tab_columns, and then iterating over those to compare old and new values and see if it was changed. The problem is once I have the column name, I don't know how to access the value in my ROWTYPE variable. Something like var.getProperty(columnName).

I wanted to do it this way to avoid having a bunch of IFs, one for each field, and it would also work directly on adding a new column to the table.

Also I can't use triggers because the higher ups said "No triggers!". (If this is indeed the only way, I could try talking to them again about this).

Comment: There are, of course, any number of ways to handle this, but in my opinion a trigger is the best approach for maintaining a history table.

Comment: @BobJarvis - a trigger is a simply mechanism for calling some code.  There is nothing we can do in a trigger that we can't do in a function like Andrei describes here.

Comment: @APC: I respectfully submit that the difference is that a trigger provides automatic execution under given conditions, e.g. ON INSERT, ON DELETE, etc. Although the same functionality can be implemented in a function, all code which maintains the base table in question must now be written to call the 'history table update' function, and my experience is that these kinds of things are prone to being forgotten, overlooked, or bypassed.  If @Andrei's management has decreed "NO TRIGGERS!" the history table update is best implemented as a procedure, but IMO a trigger would be better.  YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be worth finding out why there is a 'no triggers' rule.

There's a lot of good arguments against triggers - especially about putting business rules in triggers - but logging is generally accepted as a good case for their usage.

It's also worth looking at Oracle's built in table versioning (which records a row per update) - this keeps the shape of the history in line with the current table shape.
It doesn't give you the 'what changed' history, but it is probably better to do 'what changed' at the point when you are looking at the history, rather than adding the cost on every update.

The only way I've found of doing something like what you want - dynamically accessing a property of a %ROWTYPE, is to put a variable on a package header (so it is publicly visible) then doing dynamic PL/SQL. You could encapsulate the row variable, so long as your dynamic pl/sql block contained a local copy before each check. i.e. imagine this as your template for the execute immediate.

```
DECLARE
     lNew myTab%ROWTYPE;
     lOld myTab%ROWTYPE;
     lReturn PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    lNew := pStatefulPackage.NewRow;
    lOld := pStatefulPackage.OldRow;
    IF NVL(lNew.<variable>,'~') != NVL(lOld..<variable>,'~') THEN
        :lReturn := 1;
    END IF;
END;
```

Which is a lot of hassle to work around the fact you can't bind record variables or booleans in dynamic SQL.

It's also adding a lot of overhead on a per column basis.

Finally, I've found that ALL_TAB_COLUMNS is too slow to use for this sort of thing - you'd need to cache the metadata in local pl/sql memory.

Comment: By "Oracle's built in table versioning" I presume you mean the Total Recall (aka Flashback Archive) introduced in 11g.  I agree this is way cool and the most elegant solution, but it is only available as a chargeable extra to the Enterprise Edition license.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easiest to generate the body of the function, by reading the column names from USER_TAB_COLUMNS, e.g. (simplified, doesn't check for nulls):

```
select 'if :old.'||column_name||' <> :new.'||column_name||' then log('''||column_name||''',:old.'||column_name||',:new.'||column_name||'); end if;'
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name='MYTABLE';
```

Comment: I tried doing an EXECUTE on a something like this but I can't put my pl/sql variables in the USING clause to replace :old and :new. It gives an error saying they are not SQL types.

Comment: Ah, sorry, :old and :new are typical for triggers. My bad. Replace them with the parameter names of your function (of course without the colon)